# Row counting including transformed nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i need correct row-counting (in attribute `pos`="1", "2", etc) for the `line` element node which is partially tranforming from its child elements.
Present *counting-part* of the XSLT-code doesn't work properly. I also tried to create a variable template that would count the required node, but so far the variable is useless because it is not entirely clear how to apply it in the next step.

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>

  <line id="001" att1="aaa" att2="bbb" att3="ccc"/>
  <line id="002" att1="ddd" att2="eee" att3="fff"/>
  <line id="003" att1="ggg" att2="hhh" att3="iii">

    <subline  x="name" z="lastname"/>
    <subline  x="name2" z="lastname2"/>
    <underline  a="bar" b="foo"/>
  </line>

</entry>
```

**Desired output** (anyhow `pos=` position among attributes can be any)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry>
<entry>

  <line pos="1" id="001" att1="aaa" att2="bbb" att3="ccc"/>
  <line pos="2" id="002" att1="ddd" att2="eee" att3="fff"/>
  

  <line pos="3" id="003" att1="ggg" att2="hhh" att3="iii" x="name" z="lastname"/>
  <line pos="4" id="003" att1="ggg" att2="hhh" att3="iii" x="name2" z="lastname2"/>
  <line pos="5" id="003" att1="ggg" att2="hhh" att3="iii" a="bar" b="foo"/>

</entry>
```

**Present XSLT code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line[*]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="entry/line">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
  </xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line/*">
    <line  pos="{position()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | @*"/>
    </line>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of skipping the number 4 in your count.

Comment: just a mistake. Thanks, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/entry">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="line[not(*)] | line/*">
            <line pos="{position()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="parent::line/@* | @*"/>
            </line>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```